# How would I implement an efficient powers method in java

Tags: java, math, encryption, for-loop, theory

Say someone is doing encryption, and it requires the use of numbers greater than the max value of `long`, so I need the ability to do something just as quickly (as in few steps) and efficiently as possible. take this example. I need to take `(65^17) % LARGENUMBER`, and so I decided to use the 65^17 part like below:

65^17=65(((65^2)^2)^2)^2. (please forgive my formatting, I dont know how to do it for this equation)

Now, I have a question about what I chose. how, per say, would I implement that into a Java code line? would it just be a for loop such as:

```
int fin = 65;
int times = 17/2;
int extra = 17 % 2;
for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
    ...code...
}
```

and then what would be in the code? would it just be:

```
fin = (fin * 65) % LONGNUMBER;
```

would that even work? or what would I change about this to make it work? This is all theory by the way.

Thanks for the help, in advance :)

Comment: Did you try it? I guess that would work.

Comment: i am currently not able to try it, but will be able to later today. this question was more for information rather than a solution

Comment: You should just take `times = 17`. And there is no need of `extra` I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i calculate the remainder for extremely large exponential numbers using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616483/how-do-i-calculate-the-remainder-for-extremely-large-exponential-numbers-using-j)

Comment: In any case, you'll need something like `BigInteger`, because your `int` will just overflow. `BigInteger` has a method `modPow` that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I won't post an answer because `modPow` is already available and you should use that.  However, if you were going to do this yourself: `17/2` is not right; what you really need is `log[base 2] 17`.  And you wouldn't actually compute the log.  What you can do is set a temporary to the exponent (17) and keep shifting it one to the right.  You'd set another temporary to the base (65) and compute `base = (base * base) % modulus` each time through the loop.  Every time a bit of the temporary exponent is 1, then `product = (product * base) % modulus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's `java.math.BigInteger` class has a `modPow` method to perform modular exponentiation. Does that do what you want?

If you want to do it yourself, here is pseudocode for the "square-and-multiply" [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), which I will leave to you to translate into Java with appropriate datatypes:

```
function modPow(base, exp, mod)
    x := 1
    while exp > 0
        if exp % 2 == 1
            x := (x * base) % mod
        base := (base * base) % mod
        exp := exp // 2 # integer division
    return x
```

Comment: Small refinement: if `base` becomes 1 during the loop, you can exit early.  That's a definite possibility with modular arithmetic.

Comment: Very good answer! The `modPow` is useful just for practical uses, but the addition of the hand-made pseudocode was quite good! Both parts were appreciated, and I thank you :)